# colormap plot doesn't show all values

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I have a table which has month numbers as columns ( jan = 1, feb = 2... dec = 12) and a set of heights as indices and the data fills the columns for each month at each height.

I am trying to plot a colored map with this, with the months on x-axis and the heights on y-axis and the color depicts the densities. However, doing this eliminates some values from my data, in specific, it does not show the data for the 12th month.

This is my code:

```
times2 = df.columns;
heights = df.index
heights = heights.values.astype(np.float64)
densities = df.values

plt.pcolor(times2, heights, densities, cmap='Spectral', vmin = 0)
cb = plt.colorbar()
cb.set_label('Density of Na[atoms/cc]')

plt.ylabel('Heights[km]')
plt.xlabel('month')
plt.xticks(times2)
plt.show()
```

See image of the plot generated: there should be 12 "bins" on the x-axis.. the values for x = 12 are not plotted.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYP59.jpg

Answer (score 1):

This is an expected behavior of `pcolor()`. My guess is aside from losing the 12th month, you also missed data for the largest height. As you can see from [the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pcolor.html), the actual number of color blocks or "colored quadrilaterals" you end up plotting is `len(x) - 1` by `len(y) - 1`. You can also tell this from your plot. If you look at the x-axis, a color corresponding to your density value is plotted between 2 months (e.g. between `1` and `2`) rather than at each month.

You have 2 options to solve this problem:

1. Add one more row index in your `heights` and one more column in your `times2`. Then you won't miss any data from `densities`. After you might or might not want to adjust your `xticklabels` and `yticklabels`.
2. Just plot `densities` or your `df` by `plt.pcolor(densities, cmap='Spectral', vmin = 0)` or `plt.pcolor(df, cmap='Spectral', vmin = 0)` first. Then adjust your `xticklabels` and `yticklabels` if needed. This way `pcolor()` will actually plot all your values in `densities`:

   ```
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   import numpy as np
   import pandas as pd

   xticklabels = list('ABCDE')
   yticklabels = list('abc')
   df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, 5), index=yticklabels, columns=xticklabels)
   plt.pcolor(df, cmap='Spectral', vmin = 0)
   plt.xticks(np.arange(len(xticklabels)) + 0.5, xticklabels)
   plt.yticks(np.arange(len(yticklabels)) + 0.5, yticklabels)
   plt.colorbar()
   plt.show()
   ```

[image]